# Regex: adding quotes around words only within curly braces

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am trying to add double quotes around words only within curly braces.

Input:

```
{Cat}
{Cow Pig}
{Cat,Dog}
cat dog fish
```

Expected output:

```
{"Cat"}
{"Cow Pig"}
{"Cat","Dog"}
cat dog fish
```

Only words inside curly braces should be affected, and words can have spaces, only separated by a comma.

This is what I have tried, which almost works, but isn't capturing the group 2 (words) separate to each other.

```
({)([a-zA-z|\s|,]+?)(})
Replace with :
{"\2"}
```

DEMO: 
https://regex101.com/r/FYBOiO/1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match all the strings where you want to wrap words with double quotation marks using `{([\w\s,]+)}` regex and then wrap the words with a separate `re.sub`:

```
import re
r = r'{([\w\s,]+)}'
s = "{Cat}\n{Cow Pig}\n{Cat,Dog}\ncat dog fish"
print( re.sub(r, lambda x: "{{{}}}".format(re.sub(r'\w+', r'"\g<0>"', x.group(1))), s) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FCEJbe)

Output:

```
{"Cat"}
{"Cow" "Pig"}
{"Cat","Dog"}
cat dog fish
```

The main extraction regex is `{([\w\s,]+)}` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/eyWsvZ/2)), but you may precise it as `{\s*(\w+(?:\s*(?:,\s*)?\w+)*)\s*}` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eyWsvZ/2)).

**Details**

- `{` - a `{` char
- `([\w\s,]+)` - Group 1: one or more word, whitespace or `,` chars
- `}` - a `}` char

**Regex 2**

- `{\s*` - `{` and 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:\s*(?:,\s*)?\w+)*)` - Group 1:

  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
  - `(?:\s*(?:,\s*)?\w+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `(?:,\s*)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and 0+ whitespaces
    - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\s*}` -  0+ whitespaces and `}`